# PHP deferred string interpolation 

Tags: php, string, string-interpolation

Is there a way to 'prepare' a string for later interpolation (without using custom expansion function)?
For instance:

```
class Test {
    private static $STR_VAL = "the val is $v";

    public static function printVal($v) {
        echo self::$STR_VAL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pull the string out into a static member?

Comment: @Eric Why not? Separating the template strings from the values instead of writing every text inline somewhere in a mehod is not that uncommon.

Comment: This is just a simplified example. Imagine you need to use the string in 20 different places.

Comment: @cbaby: Isn't it the job of the `Test::printVal` to generate this string? The format string should appear in only one place - inside `printVal`. All other references should call `printVal`.

Comment: @Eric: And then you always need to search for `printVal()` to make changes to the template? Remember, that you may have much more such templates, that you may also place into a completely separate/different classes and they may be used by more than a single method.

Comment: @KingCrunch: As opposed to searching for `STR_VAL` to make a change to the template? Why is using a static method as a template any different to using a static field?

Comment: @Eric Nobody said, that this is the only place, where the OP want to use the template. And why searching, if I _know_ where to look at? (At the top of the class, not somewhere in between ;)) But because you just pointed me to "static properties": I would use constants ;)

Comment: @Eric Also, consider having 20 different functions instead of 20  fields (constants). Significant impact on code readability.

Comment: Is `public static function getVal($v) { return "the val is $v"; }` really so bad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
class Test {
    private static $STR_VAL = "the val is %s";

    public static function printVal($v) {
        echo sprintf(self::$STR_VAL, $v);
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Comment: FYI: My SEDE query: `SELECT a.Id as [Post Link], a.CreationDate
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN posts q ON q.id = a.parentid
WHERE q.tags LIKE '%<##tag?php##>%'
  AND a.PostTypeId = 2
  AND LEN(a.Body) < 300
  AND a.Body LIKE '%echo sprintf(%'
ORDER BY a.CreationDate ASC`

Comment: @mickmackusa Who told you `sprintf` is an antipattern? In contrast I learned, that `printf` is an antipattern, because you loose control, when to output what. I non-linear applications -- which are nowadays pratically every application -- this can lead to strange issues and actually nobody wants "output everywhere!!111". That aside: `sprintf` and normal string interpolation are somehow similar, whereas `sprintf` is more powerful when handling data types. I'd really like to know, where your opinion comes from. Also: Your second comment seems to belong to a different post

Comment: The SEDE query is how I am finding all Stack Overflow answers that contain `echo sprintf()`.  `sprintf()` isn't an antipattern -- I use that function all the time.  What IS an antipattern is immediately echoing the returned value of `sprintf()`. When this is desired, `printf()` should be used.  We should never see `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

A solution if you want to preserve actual variable interpolation:

```
function interpolate_string($string, $vars) {
    extract($vars);
    return eval('return "' . addslashes($string) . '";');
}

class Test {
    //Note the single quote to prevent interpolation here
    private static $STR_VAL = 'the val is $v'; 

    public static function printVal($v) {
        echo interpolate_string(self::$STR_VAL, compact('v'));
    }
}
```

While I don't see any obvious attacks in this particular code, it should be noted that the use of [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) is a possible vector for code injection when dealing with untrusted strings.